# JMM and Undesirable use of trylock

Tags: java, c++, concurrency, memory-model, java-memory-model

### Undesirable use of trylock

```
T1                                   T2
x = 42;                              while (lock.trylock())
lock.lock();                               lock.unlock();
                                     assert(x == 42);
```

In java and c++ memory model both allow  x=42  to move after lock(1).
And therefore assert could fail in T2 thread. Therefore in C++ memory model 
they defined behaviour of trylock being faling could be **spurious**.
But i didn't find what are the specs for trylock in java memory model.
**Can assert in thread 2 is guaranteed to pass in Java**. Reference would help!

**Refernce :** http://rsim.cs.illinois.edu/Pubs/08PLDI.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the javadoc for [Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html):

> Unsuccessful locking and unlocking operations, and reentrant
>   locking/unlocking operations, do not require any memory
>   synchronization effects.

Answer (score 0):

If the trylock succeeds in taking the lock, it would synchronize-with a previous lock by T1. Via Lock semantics we know there cannot be a previous lock by T1 as we enter the loop. Thus, if we enter the loop, there is no synchronize-with relation to T1.

If (or when) the trylock fails, there is no synchronize-with relation to T1. At least, if we assume that `trylock` failing is an "unsuccessful locking operation" as the [answer by jtahlborn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27790302/2361979) suggests.

Therefore in any case, there is no happens-before relation between assignment and assert. Therefore, we have a data race and the value of x might or might not be 42.

I cannot find anything *explicit* that Java `trylock` might be "spurious". However, this example has spurious behavior in Java.

Nevertheless, the [JavaDoc for trylock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#tryLock()) says

> Acquires the lock if it is available and returns immediately with the
>   value true.

but language specification beats JavaDoc in my opinion.